# Selenium not able to load dynamic options in a dropdown

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Options for a dropdown on a webpage I am testing are dependent upon the values supplied for earlier textboxes and selects (E.g. based on the currency and amount specified, dropdown for product will show appropriate values. With no values, the supplied the dropdown is blank.).

Now, although I have provided the values for currency and amount, the product dropdown is still blank. It is not fetching the filtered values based on earlier data supplied. I am using Selenium server (2.24.1) and writing scripts in Java in Eclipse with TestNG and testing on IE8.

When inspected, the dropdown is no different from others, only its options change based on the values of other elements on the page. The web application is developed in Java ([Wicket framework](http://wicket.apache.org/)).

The Selenium code:

```
selenium.select(ownerBranch, "label=4521 - Branch one");

selenium.select(currency, "label=SEK - Swedish kronor");
Thread.sleep(sleep);

selenium.type(amountSantioned,"100000");
Thread.sleep(sleep);

selenium.click(chooseLoanTermBymatDate);
Thread.sleep(sleep);

timeNow=Calendar.getInstance();
timeNow.add(Calendar.DATE,+360);selenium.type(maturityDate,dateformat.format(timeNow.getTime()));
Thread.sleep(sleep);

selenium.type(amountSantioned,"100000");
Thread.sleep(sleep);

selenium.select(serviceDelChannel, "label=BackOffice");
Thread.sleep(sleep);
selenium.select(product, "label=");
Thread.sleep(sleep*2);
selenium.select(product,"label=LN7292 - Consumer loan for Year2026");
Thread.sleep(sleep);
```

Comment: How does the page work, internally? What technology does create tha values? What does any inspection tool say to you about the element's HTML? Is it blank, are the elements in there? Could you please show us the relevant piece of your Java code as well as the HTML code of the element? Also! Did you try any other browser?

Comment: Ok I will try with your improvements and revert u back the status
   Thanks

Comment: I am tried with IE8. But it is still not working.When inspected the dropdown is no different than others only its options changes based upon the values for other elements on the page.My application is developed in Java (Wicket framework). I am pasting java code of my testscript down here : It is pasted in two parts .please look over it

Comment: selenium.select(ownerBranch, "label=4521 - Branch one");
  selenium.select(currency, "label=SEK - Swedish kronor");
  Thread.sleep(sleep);
continued in next cmt
  selenium.type(amountSantioned,"100000");
  Thread.sleep(sleep);
  selenium.click(chooseLoanTermBymatDate);
  Thread.sleep(sleep);
  timeNow=Calendar.getInstance();
  timeNow.add(Calendar.DATE,+360);
  selenium.type(maturityDate,dateformat.format(timeNow.getTime()));
  Thread.sleep(sleep);
  selenium.type(amountSantioned,"100000");
  Thread.sleep(sleep);
  selenium.select(serviceDelChannel, "label=BackOffice");
  Thread.sleep(sleep);

Comment: selenium.select(product, "label=");
  Thread.sleep(sleep*2);
  selenium.select(product,"label=LN7292 - Consumer loan for Year2026");
  Thread.sleep(sleep);

Comment: @Slanec please look into it .

Comment: Can selenium.Fireevent command be useful.?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to try to reproduce the issue (if you can point me to a publicly visible site with similar behaviour, I might test it), so I'm only taking a guess here:

Since Selenium RC is written in pure Javascript and "only" firing `change` events on selecting values from drop-downs, Wicket is probably waiting for something else or relying on a completely different mechanism.

Things you can try:

- Use Selenium WebDriver. Selenium RC has been deprecated for over a year now, because it had serious technical limitations (you might have just bumped into one) that are now solved by WebDriver. Also, you won't ever have to use `Thread.sleep()` again (although I'm almost sure it could be got rid of even here, mostly). This solution is the most painful, but is almost guaranteed to work well, because WebDriver behaves like a real user.
- Call [`selenium.fireEvent()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#fireEvent%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) on all the `input` elements you're interacting with. [Useful events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/) might be `focus`, `blur`, maybe even `click` in between them.
- Calling `selenium.keyPressNative(String.valueOf(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER))` (presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> natively) after you every change of a dropdown. If the changed dropdown is not focused before this, you might need to [`focus()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#focus%28java.lang.String%29) it beforehand.
- The painful way that tries to simulate user's behaviour as close as possible instead of using JS methods: Instead of using `select()`, try to [`focus()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#focus%28java.lang.String%29) a dropdown element, then select one of its options by [pressing](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#keyPressNative%28java.lang.String%29) <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> repeatedly, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I have been using selenium server for last 6 months, with it not be troublesome to move to webdriver. Actually I have no idea how a webdriver works i use testNG in eclipse.

Comment: To get the difference and for a basic example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007819/what-is-the-difference-between-seleniums-remote-control-vs-webdriver and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285641/selenium-rc-architechture-and-selenium-web-driver-architechture-differences. Also, after you try something to work out the problem, be sure to tell me how it worked :).

Comment: Thanks a lot , It worked .First I used fireevent with event "blur" on all my input elements used on the page and then I used the event focus on all my input elements on page.i don't know if I can reduce on the numbner of events called or the number of elements on which I need to use fireevent. But I am carrying on with a default on all elements.Anyway Its a great relief to get rid of it for me and my seniors.Thanks a lot from my team.